# wsadmin script timing out when executing against DMGR via SOAP

Tags: soap, websphere, business-process-management, wsadmin

I'm attempting to start and stop an application on a single JVM via the wsadmin console since the Web UI for IBM BPM PS Adv. doesn't allow for that kind of operation. So, I have the following script:

https://gist.github.com/predatorian3/b8661c949617727630152cbe04f78d7e

and when I run it against the DMGR from the Cell Host, I receive the following errors.

```
[wasadmin@server01 ~]$ cat /usr/local/bin/Run_wsadmin.sh
#!/bin/bash
#
#
#

/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/bin/wsadmin.sh -lang jython -user serviceAccount -password password $*

[wasadmin@cessoapscrt00 ~]$ time Run_wsadmin.sh -f /opt/IBM/wsadmin/wsadmin_Restart_Application.py WPS00 CRT00WPS01 redirectResource_war
WASX7209I: Connected to process "dmgr" on node CRTDMGR using SOAP connector;  The type of process is: DeploymentManager
WASX7303I: The following options are passed to the scripting environment and are available as arguments that are stored in the argv variable: "[WPS00, CRT00WPS01, redirectResource_war]"
WASX7017E: Exception received while running file "/opt/IBM/wsadmin/wsadmin_Restart_Application.py"; exception information: com.ibm.websphere.management.exception.ConnectorException
org.apache.soap.SOAPException: [SOAPException: faultCode=SOAP-ENV:Client; msg=Read timed out; targetException=java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out]


real    3m21.275s
user    0m17.411s
sys     0m0.796s
```

So, I'm not specifying the connection types, and using the default, which is SOAP. However, upon [reading about the other Connection Types](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/info/ae/ae/rxml_commandline.html), none of them seem any better, but I attribute that to IBM Documentation vagueness. Is there an option to increase the timeout wait periods, or turn it off, or is there a better connection type?

Also running this directly on the wsadmin console, it seems that it is hanging up on gathering the application manager string.

```
[wasadmin@server01 ~]$ Run_wsadmin.sh
WASX7209I: Connected to process "dmgr" on node CRTDMGR using SOAP connector;  The type of process is: DeploymentManager WASX7031I: For help, enter: "print Help.help()"
wsadmin>appManager = AdminControl.queryNames('cell=CRTCELL,node=WPS00,type=ApplicatoinManager,process=CRT00WPS01,*')
WASX7015E: Exception running command: "appManager = AdminControl.queryNames('cell=CRTCELL,node=WPS00,type=ApplicationManager,process=CRT00WPS01,*')"; exception information:
 com.ibm.websphere.management.exception.ConnectorException
org.apache.soap.SOAPException: [SOAPException: faultCode=SOAP-ENV:Client; msg=Read timed out; targetException=java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out]

wsadmin>
```

Comment: Are you sure that cell,node, server names are correct? And that node and server are up and running?

Comment: Yes, when I search for those processes they do show up. The script was working until a certain application was installed.

Answer (score 0):

You can increase timeout value in **{profile}/properties/soap.client.props**

```
com.ibm.SOAP.requestTimeout=180
```

Comment: I corrected my spelling, and still had timeouts. However, can I add the option `-javaoption "-Dcom.ibm.SOAP.requestTimeout=0"` to the command line argument, or does it have to be in the configuration file?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to turn off timeout, modify com.ibm.SOAP.requestTimeout=0
Or if you want longer timeout you can modify the value 180 to something else.
Also about your query command, I noticed that you have a typo on the MBean type, you had type=ApplicatoinManager, it should be type=ApplicationManager

Comment: I corrected my spelling, and still had timeouts. However, can I add the option `-javaoption "-Dcom.ibm.SOAP.requestTimeout=0"` to the command line argument, or does it have to be in the configuration file?

Answer (score 0):

HERE YOU GO -- I had the same issue. I want to override the timeout prop temporarily. This worked like a champ. Make sure you follow below steps exactly.I did some mistakes and the prop did not passed, I figured out and it works.

Copy the soap.client.props file from /properties and give it a new name such as mysoap.client.props.
Edit mysoap.client.props and update the value of com.ibm.SOAP.requestTimeout as required
Create a new Java properties file soap_override.props and enter the following line:
com.ibm.SOAP.ConfigURL=file:/mysoap.client.props 
Pass soap_override.props into wsadmin using the -p option: wsadmin -p soap_override.props...

REFERENCE:
https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/timdp/entry/avoiding_wsadmin_request_timeouts_the_neat_way32?lang=en

Answer (score 0):

I feel that my problem is not connecting but not timeout. I tried changing the configuration of com.ibm.SOAP.requestTimeout to 0, and then it kept connecting without any sign of disconnection.